# socket taking to long in fin_wait_1

Tags: java, windows, tcp

Getting this strange behavior and dont know if **SO_LINGER(0)** is the "best way" to solve it.

This only happens when i have this 2 factors together:

- OS - windows
- lower internet bandwidth

When this 2 factors combine, my tcp connections (client-side), right after calling close()  get stuck in **FIN_WAIT**  and then **TIME_WAIT** for a long, long time

(In this network, the exact same app running in other OS behaves as expected. The same applies to windows but in a better network connection)

In this particular case i just bother with fin_wait _(1 or 2) states. My first thougth is to set so_linger to 0, but i'm not completely convinced that abortive close is the right (or the only) option here.

Any idea on how can i handle this ? Is there other way to force windows to close that connections (programmatically) ?

**( EDIT )**

```
EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup(); try {
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(group)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)
            // .option(ChannelOption.SO_LINGER, 0)   ( ?? )
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                    p.addLast(new MyHandler());
                    p.addLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
                    ch.config()
                            .setSendBufferSize(TCP_BUF_SIZE)
                            .setReceiveBufferSize(TCP_BUF_SIZE);
                }
            });

    ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync();
    channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();

} finally {
    group.shutdownGracefully(); }
```

Comment: please add  part of your code.